# Preload videos on StumbleUpon Video

Tags: video, stumbleupon

I like using the video service from StumbleUpon to discover new videos on the web but I often find myself waiting between each video.

Is there a way to preload the next video while watching the current one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not natively with the way StumbleUpon is set up.

What you can do is something old school and it goes a little something like this:

1. Load up two tabs, each with their own StumbleUpon video
2. As you watch one, have the other tab on pause and loading the video into the buffer
3. When you're done with the current tab, hit stumble!
4. Before the next video starts to fully play, hit pause
5. Go to the other tab.
6. Flip back and forth between the tabs, loading and pausing as you do.

Comment: That's what I was doing when my network was really slow. So I guess we will have to wait for StumbleUpon to add code to load a frame or something else in the background...